# Organizing a cross-platform library + GUI project

Tags: c++, qt

We're working on a library project (hence the need for platform independence). Thankfully, the library is a template library that (unfortunately) still has non-template dependencies (like GMP) so I guess creating a shared library out of this whole project is not so much of an option (my limited C++ understanding might be wrong, correct me).

We decided to use CMake for the library and so far it has worked well on a Mac / (likely Linux too). Now however, we decided to build a GUI around this library and have decided to use the Qt framework given that it can be used cross-platform.

The question is then if it makes sense to separately maintain a CMake project and a Qt project since Qt already has QMake for cross-platform compilation?

Comment: CMake has full Qt support already.